# Python dynamic class name creation

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have the following setup:

```
test.py
test\
    __init__.py
    abstract_handler.py
    first_handler.py
    second_handler.py
```

first_handler.py and second_handler.py contain classes with the same names that inherit from abstract_handler.

What I want to do in test.py is: given a string containing "first_handler" or any other handler class, create an object of that class.

Most solutions I found assume that the classes are in the same module (test.py), I don't know how to dynamically import the specific required class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `__import__` for importing. Note that if you use submodules, you have to specify the `fromlist`, otherwise you get the top-level module instead. Thus

```
__import__('foo.bar', fromlist=['foo']).__dict__['baz_handler']()
```

Will call `foo.bar.baz_handler()`

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary for this sort of dispatching.

```
import first_handler
import second_handler

dispatch_dict = {
    'first': first_handler.FirstHandler
    'second': second_handler.SecondHandler
}
```

Now, assuming your choice is in `choice_string`:

```
instance = dispatch_dict[choice_string]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this:

```
from first_handler import SameName as handler1
from second_handler import SameName as handler2

handlers = {'UniqueName1': handler1,
            'UniqueName2': handler2}

instance = handlers['UniqueName1']()
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
import abstract_handler
import first_handler
import second_handler

output = globals()['first_handler']()
```

Comment: Although I have the feeling this is frowned upon somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A broad answer to the question.

To dynamically import use `__import__(string)` and then you'll find all the objects in `.__dict__`

This way you can instance based on a strings like:

```
c = __import__('test.first_handler').__dict__['awesomeclassname']()
```